# MongoDB is much slower than PostgreSQL in python, when it should not be

Tags: python, mongodb, postgresql

I am writing an IOT server on Django for agricultural machines (each machine has a unique code name "imei", also each data in iot database has location or point, datetime, course and etc.).

Now, I am working with PostgreSql database which is indexed by imei and datetime. There are already 180 million rows from many different machines (consequently, different imeis). So, now I want to optimize my solution with Postgres by changing the database to MongoDB, where each machine (imei) will be saved in separate collections which are indexed by datetime. Thus, each collection will only hold data for one machine.

Postgres:

- Save all data over all machines in one table
- Indexes are over imei, datetime

MongoDB:

- Saves each machine in separate collection
- Index is over datetime

However, when I query and retrieve the same data for one machine from Postgres and MongoDB, Postgres is much faster than MongoDB. I think that it should not be like that because accessing data from 180 million raws should take a long time because of an extra query through machines, whereas, in MongoDb it should be faster because it will not query over machines' imeis.

```
def postgres_check():
    import time
    time_1 = time.time()
    query = ShortPacket.objects.using('production').filter(imei='866795036926614', date_time__gte=check_date_start, date_time__lte=check_date_end)
    data = []
    for each in query.values('date_time', 'point', 'speed', 'course', 'fuel').order_by('date_time').iterator():
        pass
    time_2 = time.time()
    print(f"POSTGRES: Num of points {query.count()} in {time_2 - time_1} secs")

def mongo_check():
    import time
    from mongoengine.context_managers import switch_collection
    time_1 = time.time()
    with switch_collection(Packet, '866795036926614') as PacketImei:
        query = PacketImei.objects(date_time__gte=check_date_start, date_time__lte=check_date_end).values_list('date_time', 'point', 'speed', 'course', 'fuel')
        for each in query:
            pass
        time_2 = time.time()
        print(f"MONGO: Num of points {query.count()} in {time_2 - time_1} secs")

# ShortPacket is django model in PostgreSQL
# Packet is django-mongoengine model in MongoDB
# ShortPacket and Packet models have save attributes
```

---

Here my code when I access the data with postgres and mongo

Performance when iterating over data:

```
POSTGRES: Num of points 79122 in 1.8221182823181152
MONGO: Num of points 79122 in 4.601069450378418
```

Performance when save data to file:

```
POSTGRES: Num of points 79122 in 2.573782444000244 secs
MONGO: Num of points 79122 in 13.049479246139526 secs
```

Data structure was identical and both databases run on the same server, so all external factors are the same. So, am I doing something wrong? Or Postgres indexing is working better than MongoDB query in separate collections?

Comment: "*Indexes are over imei, datetime*" - do you mean you have two indices, one for `imei` and one for datetime, or that you have a single multi-column index over `imei, datetime`? Because that's what you should use.

Comment: @Bergi, I have multi-column index over imei and datetime

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you. I have updated the code without an image

Comment: For completeness, measure postgres with table per imei and mongodb with one collection. You may find something interesting.

Comment: @A.Rauan Then that's the optimal index setup, where Postgres can look up the imei and then get all the rows in the datetime order, from that index. Not sure why you would expect MongoDB to be faster than that?

Comment: You are not only comparing postgres vs mongo performance here, your test also includes the ORM overhead (MongoEngine vs whatever you are using for Postgres). 
Use the driver (pymongo) directly instead of MongoEngine to see if the overhead is coming from MongoEngine and do the same with your Postgres ORM.